# Django. Значение в зависимости от значений в БД

Tags: python, django

(Процесс должен быть таким и не каким другим!) Есть Объект в БД с полями `t1, t2, t3, t4, t5`. Каждое из них цифровое IntegerField. По умолчанию равно 0 `default=0`. 
В шаблоне есть число(скажем `х`), которое в зависимости от t`1, t2, t3, t4, t5` разное. А именно когда они все равны 0, то `х=0`, но если одно из них принимет любое другое число, то `х` меняется на число, равное числу не равных нулю значений :)  пример:

```
t1=0, t2=1, t3=0, t4=2, t5=0 =>>> x=2 (т.к. t2, t4 не равные 0).
```

Вопрос: каким образом это описать во вьюхе и передать в шаблон?
Вариант с перечислением if/else всех вариантов... ну уж простите...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5) # используем кортеж для удобства работы, можно использовать и список
```

Запишем алгоритм "в лоб" (как в описании):

```
x = 0
for item in t:
    if item != 0:
        x += 1
print(x)
```

Все хорошо, но 4 строки - это слишком много. 
Можно воспользоваться генераторами:
создадим список из исходного - из элементов, не равных нулю, и возьмем его длину

```
x = len(list(item for item in t if item != 0))
```

аналогичный вариант - если воспользуемся не генератором, а фильтром:

```
x = len(list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, t))) 
# в python3 функция filter возвращает итератор - поэтому требуется преобразование в список, 
# в python2 работает и len(filter(lambda x: x != 0, t))
```

или функцией reduce (если кратко описать назначение - умеет пробегать по списку и отдавать либо сумму, либо произведение элементов):

```
from functools import reduce # python 3 - функция reduce перемещена в functools
x = reduce(lambda x, y: x + 1 if y != 0 else x, t)
```

*Для справки:*

**lambda-функция** - это анонимная функция. Так обычно объявляют маленькие встроенные функции. До ":" перечисляются аргументы, после - выражение, возвращаемое в качестве результата.
Объявления:

```
def check(x):
    return x > 0
```

и

```
check = lambda x: x > 0
```

эквивалентны

Answer (score 2):

Функция `filter` в Python 2.7 возвращает список, удовлетворяющий [лямбда-функции](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php). И мы берём его длину.

```
def counter:
  ...
  raw_list = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5]
  list_of_not_null = filter(lambda x: x!=0, raw_list)
  ...
  return len(list_of_not_null)
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, но было бы еще лучше, если бы вы прокомментировали код хотя бы парой строк

Comment: согласен, так же возникает ошибка: object of type 'filter' has no len()

Comment: @FlatOMG Какую версию Python вы используете? `filter` гарантированно вернет список, если вы передали ему корректные входные данные. А к любому списку применим `len()`. Смотрите внимательно, что вы передаете в `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

```
value = 0
for attr in ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']:
    value += 1 if getattr(your_model, attr, 0) else 0
```

потом засовываете `value` в `content` для шаблона. По сути это те же if/else, но короче.